# Android: design fragments as cards

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-fragments, background

I have a ViewPager which contains a couple of Fragments which are available by swiping left/right. I want these Fragments to look like cards but I can't seem to get it right.

[image]

The fragment occupies the whole space and the shadow is surrounding the card.  Instead I would like to have some padding between the fragment layout and the ViewPager one so when I scroll there would be some space between fragments. This is what I want it to look like more or less

[image]

This is my layout for the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".Main"
android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
android:background="@drawable/bg_card"

 >


<EditText
android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number" />

<EditText
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the card drawable:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
        android:dither="true">

        <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

        <solid android:color="#aaa" />
        <padding android:bottom="8dp"
            android:left="8dp"
            android:right="8dp"
            android:top="8dp" />

    </shape>
</item>

<item android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
        android:dither="true">

        <corners android:radius="2dp" />

        <solid android:color="#fff" />

        <padding android:bottom="8dp"
            android:left="8dp"
            android:right="8dp"
            android:top="8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for CardView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#CardView

Comment: Wasn't this only for version 5.0? Or it can be used for earlier versions as well?

Comment: The support library widgets are backwards compatible! Though you will want to read the documentation for CardView to see what differences there might be (for example, 5.0 has elevation, but CardView mimics elevation on pre 5.0 devices by adjusting shadow size)

Comment: You're right. I did managed to include the library and create the card. Thanks!